# Count values in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table which I want to use to store events.

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
```

T have four types of events: info, warning, error, Critical

I need to count them in order to display the values into Bar Chart.

Is it possible to create SQL query which returns four values. For example:

```
info       12,
warning    332,
error      442,
Critical   23
```

I need only the type and the count.

Comment: So `type` is the column that has the 4 distinct values and you just want a count of the number of rows in the table with each value?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: group by type and use count()

Comment: @maraca can you write the complete answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want a simple aggregation

```
SELECT type, count(*)
  FROM events
 GROUP BY type
 ORDER BY (CASE type WHEN 'info' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'warning' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'error' THEN 3
                     WHEN 'critical' THEN 4
            END) asc
```

It's not obvious to me whether (or how) you are sorting the data.  I would expect that you'd want to store a sort order somewhere so that you don't have dozens of queries that implement the same sort order that have to be changed in the future when you add another `type`.

Comment: In this case I don't need sorting I just need only to count the events by type.

Answer (score 2):

You can see [*GROUP BY*](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) reference for aditional information

```
SELECT type, count(*)
FROM events
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output in these two ways:

```
SELECT type,COUNT(*) FROM EVENTS GROUP BY type;
SELECT DISTINCT type, COUNT(*) over(partition BY type) FROM EVENTS;
```